# C++ variadic template function with non-template

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

So i am trying to replace multiple similar member functions with a variadic template, as the functions all do the same and forward some of their parameters to a different function. I tried to replace these two functions:

```
void function(T a, T b, double c, bool d = false)
{
    if (!isStateMemoryFixed) isStateMemoryFixed = true;
    helper.help(a, b, c);
    if (d) doStuff();
}
void function(T a, T b, T e, double c, bool d = false)
{
    if (!isStateMemoryFixed) isStateMemoryFixed = true;
    helper.help(a, b, e, c);
    if (d) doStuff();
}
```

with this

```
template<typename... Ts>
void function(Ts... ts, bool d= false)
{
        if (!isStateMemoryFixed) isStateMemoryFixed = true;
        helper.help(ts...);
        if (d) doStuff();
}
```

and call it like i would before:

```
void test()
{
    T a,b,e;
    double c;
    Obj obj;
    obj.function(a,b,e,c,true);
}
```

but I get an error: "no instance of template ... matches the argument list". 
I am new to variadic templates, but what I have been reading suggests that I should be able to do this.

Comment: `Ts...` will remain empty, because it cannot be automatically determined when it isn't the last parameter. So effectively you call a function that only has a `bool` parameter, hence the error message.

Comment: To put it another way, how is the compiler to know when `true` is part of `ts` and when it is a non-default value for `d`? So the rule is that the variadic parameter goes at the end of the parameter list (which unfortunately conflicts with having a default value for `d`).

Comment: [OT]: `if (!isStateMemoryFixed) isStateMemoryFixed = true;` should probably be replaced by `isStateMemoryFixed = true;`.

Comment: What is the type `T`?  Because if convertable from `int` what would `function(1,1,1,1)` supposed to call prior to your change?

Comment: Sorry... your correction to my answer was right... I've rejected it by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

As said by Johannes Schaub and by Bo Persson, the variadic parameters must be at the end of the list.

So, IMHO, a better-than-nothing-solution (caution: not tested) can be rewrite the function in this way (assuming the `c` parameter is mandatory and even of type `double`).

```
template<typename... Ts>
void function(double c, bool d, Ts... ts)
{
        if (!isStateMemoryFixed) isStateMemoryFixed = true;
        helper.help(c, ts...);
        if (d) doStuff();
}
```

It's not equivalent: you loose the default `false` value for `d`.

The call become

```
function(c, true, a, b, e);
```